# Generating and solving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following question:

> Assume that a rocket-driven car can accelerate proportionally to its speed with the force $F_1=\alpha v$ and $\alpha=320 \ln(2) \frac{kg}{s}.$ If the mass of the car including the driver is $M=640\ $kg, how long does it take for the rocket car to accelerate from $v_0=100\frac{km}{h}$ to $200\frac{km}{h}$ (i.e. double in speed)?

**My attempt:**

$$M\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\alpha \frac{dx}{dt}.$$
or:
$$mv'=\alpha v,$$
I have used the following method in attempt to solve:
for De's of form:

$$y'+Py=Q$$
the solution: is of form:
$$ye^I=\int Q e^I dt + C $$
where
$$I=\int P dt$$
so in this case we get a solution:
$$v=Ce^{\frac{\alpha}{M}t}$$
This is where my problem comes in, if i consider:
$$v_0=Ce^{\frac{\alpha}{M}t_0}$$
and
$$2v_0=Ce^{\frac{\alpha}{M}t_1}$$
I don't know how to solve. Also, I think that my solution is incorrect anyway as I have tried to substitute it back into the DE and could not get to zero. If someone could give me some advice as to where I have gone wrong, that'd be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've set up your differential up correctly and got the proper solution. As a slight note to this, you could have solved the equation using separation of variables, which would have been a bit more straightforward than what you had done. Either way, you get the same solution so it's fine.

For simplicity, let's just take $v(0) = v_0$. This way, we can see that $C = v_0$ and the solution is

$$v(t) = v_0e^{\frac{a}{M}t}$$

So to find when $v(t) = 2v_0$ we can solve

$$2v_0 = v_0e^{\frac{a}{M}t}$$

$$\implies 2 = e^{\frac{a}{M}t}$$

$$\implies t = \frac{M}{a}\ln{2}$$

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how is it that you know $C=v_0$?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late here, but the reason why is because since we have the initial condition $v(0) = v_0$, then we can plug this information into our general equation:

$v_0 = Ce^{\frac{a}{M}*0} = C$

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your help I understand now :)